How can I sort Dropbox tagged images in my Embedder app?
I have a HTML page that offers a textbox in which the viewer can write certain keywords. After clicking ENTER, the images are loaded in iframes according to the keywords. My problem is: how do I write this is JS so that it can be integrated on a Dropbox Embedder app? Also, I did not find a way to know if I should tag all images in Dropbox or modify their metadata in advance? Thanks in advance.
I expect that all images with same keyword are shown in page, inside their respective iframes.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Discuss-Dropbox-Developer-API/Embedder-and-tags/td-p/796048 ]
